# cannot import sdl2.sdlgfx: ImportError: found ['libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0'], but it's not usable for the library SDL2_gfx

Tags: python3, sdl

I've succeeded to import sdl2.sdlgfx with the latest upstream release.

---

When I going to import sdl2.sdlgfx, it fails.
If you succeed to import, please comment how to do this.

I tried like below.

```
$ python3
Python 3.11.2 (main, May 30 2023, 17:45:26) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sdl2.sdlgfx
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdl2/dll.py:234: DLLWarning: TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'")
  warnings.warn(repr(exc), DLLWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdl2/sdlgfx.py", line 53, in <module>
    dll = DLL("SDL2_gfx", ["SDL2_gfx", "SDL2_gfx-1.0"],
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdl2/dll.py", line 236, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("found %s, but it's not usable for the library %s" %
RuntimeError: found ['libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0'], but it's not usable for the library SDL2_gfx

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sdl2/sdlgfx.py", line 56, in <module>
    raise ImportError(exc)
ImportError: found ['libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0'], but it's not usable for the library SDL2_gfx
>>>
```

environment:

- Ubuntu 23.04
- packages

  - libsdl2-2.0-0, libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0, libsdl2-image-2.0-0, libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0, libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0, python3-sdl2

Comment: I've succeeded to import sdl2.sdlgfx with latest upstream release.

Answer (score 1):

import sdl2.sdlgfx with the latest upstream release.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1310870)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477593/cannot-import-sdl2-sdlgfx-importerror-found-libsdl2-gfx-1-0-so-0-but-its#comment2588181_1477593

Comment: You're right, the answer has been given in a comment by the TO 11 days _before_ your answer. I considered that to be plagiarism and therefore marked your answer for deletion. At least, you could have been so polite to create this answer as "community", don't you think?